# Как вывести emoji смайлики в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Какой модуль можно использовать для вывода emoji в python?

Comment: Выводить откуда, куда и зачем? Что вам мешает выводить без модуля?

Comment: Ну так правильно, вы попытались отпечатать переменную с названием ``, но это некорректное название для переменной. Названия переменных могут содержать только буквы, цифры и символ подчёркивания, а Emoji в названиях переменных помещать нельзя.

Comment: тоесть если я присвою перемнной emoji, а затем выведу её то все будет ок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выводимый текст надо помещать в кавычки:

```
print("")
```

Или так

```
x = ""
print(x)
```

Comment: Уже вижу, как виндовая консоль ищет в таблице cp866 этот символ :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Это уже тонкости :) В андроиде работает 

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev под winodws в IDLE такую строку даже вставить нельзя, или не реагирует или сразу закрывается. И открыть файл с такой строкой тоже нельзя - открывается пустой.

Comment: в любом случае выведет это (???????)

Comment: @Олег в "любом случае" из какого набора случаев? В моем случае выводит нормально: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s871O.png